# Keeping intent receiver alive beyond the activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created a Activity with few toggle buttons and based on the selection would like to perform specific operations at specific intervals. I have created the broadcast receiver and doing these activities in the onReceive(). I am using the alarm manager to run these tasks at particular intervals. If I don't un-register the recever in onDestroy I get an error saying there is leak, if I unregister the receiver in onDestroy it works fine but the receiver stops working.
I would like to keep the register listening even after the activity is closed, so that I keep performing particular tasks and specified interval. Please suggest

Comment: this is like a comment

Answer (score -1):

what you are looking for is a sticky broadcastreceiver. the best example i found so far is visible here -->  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver_sticky

> A normal broadcast intent is not available anymore after is was send
>   and processed by the system. If you use the
>   sendStickyBroadcast(Intent) method, the corresponding intent is
>   sticky, meaning the intent you are sending stays around after the
>   broadcast is complete.